# Should node-ampqlib rabbitMQ channel be closed in following case?

Tags: rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I have defined `enqueueMessage` function to enqueue the message to rabbitMQ queue. In the first line of the function I am creating channel. Which means every time I call `enqueueMessage` a channel is created. Is this the right approach or should I created top level `channel` variable and reuse it?

If I create top level channel should I do some more coding to handle case channel gets closed automatically for some reason (network broke)

```
export async function enqueueMessage(queue: string, message: object) {
  const channel = await connection.createChannel();
  await channel.assertQueue(queue);
  channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `channel` is cheap but not that much. It depends on the rate of call of this method. but generally, you should create a top-level `channel` but be aware that `channels` are not thread-safe so you have to care.

And regarding your next question, yes sure, you have to handle it. there are some Auto Recovery options available in some client libraries. for example in
[Java](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery) you can use this code :

`factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);`

And in my experience, there are some cases that the connection gets closed on the server so I had to handle `AlreadyClosedException` too.